# Create Rows+Columns from 2 lists in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have 2 lists with different numbers of elements in the each list. And I want to create `csv` file with values from these lists like:

```py
projects = ['Project_1', 'Project_2', 'Project_3', ..., 'Project_N']
components = ['component_1', 'component_2', 'component_3', ..., 'component_N']
```

| **Component / Project** | Project_1 | Project_2 | Project_3 | ... | Project_N →→→ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| component_1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| component_2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| component_3 |  |  |  |  |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |
| component_N ↓↓↓ |  |  |  |  |  |

Important: Items from the `projects` list must be in the file as a header.

But when I trying to create `csv` file with `pandas` I get error:

```py
def create_csv():
    pd.DataFrame(data=[components], columns=projects).to_csv('test.csv', index=False)

create_csv()
```

`ValueError: 11 columns passed, passed data had 196 columns`

Can you please tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: If you have 11 projects, how do the 196 component values map to them?

Comment: I don't know how to separate rows and columns in dataframe. Because my lists have different number of elements inside, as I said originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

projects = ['Project_1', 'Project_2', 'Project_3']  # Add all your project names here
components = ['component_1', 'component_2', 'component_3']  # Add all your component names here

# Create an empty DataFrame with projects as columns and components as index
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=projects, index=components)
df.index.name = 'Component / Project' 

# Save to CSV
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Maybe you can tell me how to specify the name Component/Project in the first column of the first row? If it's possible..

Comment: df.index.name = 'Component / Project'

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Also it looks really weird, what you try to do:

```
#Add 'Component / Projects' to the front of your project row

x = 'Component / Project'
projects = ['Project_1', 'Project_2', 'Project_3', ..., 'Project_N']
projects =  x.insert(0, projects)


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=projects, index=components)

df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you! Why is that weird? Each project has a list of components, everything seems to be logical. I don't know how it can be displayed differently in the table.

Comment: it looks weird, as you give back an empty table somehow, I would have expected some input inside

Comment: Unfortunately, this will be the next step in my script. I need to figure out how to populate this table according to what components each project has.